# How long does the result of an ADX operation persist?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/operations#show-operation-details) doc , results of certain operations such as async export do persist. But it's not mentioned how long they stay/persist in ADX? By 'operation result' I am referring to something that can be obtained by the following control command:-

```
.show operation <OperationId> details
```

Docs don't seem to mention any retention threshold. I have seen results vanishing in 5 days after export(async mode) as well. Another related question is -- is there a way to change retention of these results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations history should be retained for 14 days. The period isn't configurable.

If you're seeing differently, I'd recommend you open a support ticket with the details.

It's also possible to some of the information exported as diagnostics logs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs